# How to define a "List" of derived classes?

Tags: c#, class, types, derived

I have a base class and some derived classes

```
public class MyBase {...}
public class MyClass1 : MyBase {...}
public class MyClass2 : MyBase {...}
```

Now I want to make a list of these derived classes (classes!! Not instances of classes!), and then I want to create one instance of one of these derived class randomly.

How does this work??

Here what I want in pseudo C# :)

```
List<MyBase> classList = new List<MyBase> () { MyClass1, MyClass2, MyClass3, ...}

MyBase randomInstance = new classList[random.Next(0,classList.Count-1)]();
```

(unfortunately this List construction expects instances of MyBase but not class names)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like (assuming a no-args constructor and that B and C are derived from A):

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type> { typeof(A), typeof(B), typeof(C) };

A instance = (A)Activator.CreateInstance(types[r.Next(0, types.Count)]);
```

Comment: Don't forget that to use this approach, each of the types in the list must have constructors with identical semantics. A default no-argument constructor will do , but so long as each type has a constructor with the same signature, you're good to go.

Comment: Caveat: the only real benefit to this approach is brevity. The compiler won't keep you from shooting yourself in the foot since it's all runtime type info.

Comment: When you want to deal with an uncertain type (outside of generics) you lose type safety anyways.

Answer (score 5):

You can create from types like this

```
class MyBase
{
}

class MyClass1 : MyBase
{
}

class MyClass2 : MyBase
{
}
```

This uses [System.Activator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4wc81dc.aspx) to create the object.

```
void Main()
{
    var typesToPickFrom = new List<Type>()
    {
        typeof(MyBase),
        typeof(MyClass1),
        typeof(MyClass2)
    };

    var rnd = new Random();
    Type typeToCreate = typesToPickFrom [rnd.Next(typesToPickFrom.Count)];
    object newObject = Activator.CreateInstance(typeToCreate);
}
```

You can cast as needed.

Comment: I was going to say you've got an off-by-1 overflow issue in your indexer, but I forgot that the upper bound is exclusive. Fixed my own answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

If, as you say, you want to "create" a random instance:

```
var selection = random.Next(0,2)

switch (selection)
{
    case 1: return new MyBase();
    case 2: return new MyClass1();
    case 3: return new MyClass2();
}
```

It might be useful to define a common `interface` for all of these classes, so that you can return something from the method.  Or you can simply return an `object` or a `dynamic`.

Comment: The return type would probably be `MyBase`, since all the classes are or inherit from `MyBase`.